# Change bar tint color of UISearchBar - iOS

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar in my navigation bar, I changed its bar tint color to be the same as the background color of my nav bar, but there are 2 black lines, on the top and on the bottom of my searchBar, how can I remove them?

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

I added this line of code, this way I don't need to set my bar tint color to be the same as my nav bar color

```
self.searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your approach to achieve that, but I can suggest one way to do so.

don't know will it help you or not..!

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10.0, 100.0, 44.0)];
searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
searchBar.delegate = self;
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;
```

Comment: I do this, because I want to remove the border of the search bar, so when I set its style to minimal, the color of the white inside textbook changes, and I want to keep it white.

Comment: my nav bar is a custom nav bar, so I can write self.navigationItem